# Using global variables in chef ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to define some variable as global in a chef recipe.Like I am declaring & changing a var in a chef resource and later i want to use this changed value in the recipe code.

```
version=""
ruby 'extract_module' do
    #cwd ::File.dirname(C:\\chef\\cache)
    code <<-EOH
        require 'win32/registry'
        Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open(
        'Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall') do |reg|
            reg.each_key do |key|
                k = reg.open(key)
                app = k["DisplayName"] rescue nil

                if app == "Qlik Sense 3.2"
                    version = k["DisplayVersion"] rescue nil
                    puts version
                end
            end
        end
    EOH
end

puts "#{version}"
```

This variable is not printing outside the ruby resource. Can we do something like python, declare with global keyword & modify the value. Any similar here?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation so it is readable.

Comment: What @coderanger said and also It appears you have an extra `end` prior to `EOH` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ruby` resource doesn't run in the same process, it runs `ruby -E` as a subprocess. What you want is a `ruby_block` resource, which is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indentation is not the issue. I just want to know if there is some way I can use the "version" variable outside the ruby resource of my recipe code. Just like making a variable global. Thanks again.

Comment: My answer isn't related to indentation.

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed it. Yes, I got it now. The chef resources do not run in the same process as the main ruby code,hence variables are out of scope. Does it create a separate subprocess for each resource I declare ,normally subprocess.popen etc also creates a subprocess from the main process but the execution of the subprocess can be returned to the main process.Anything similar is possible here? Thanks in advance.